# How can I add a checkbox in BI Publisher?

Tags: bi-publisher

I am trying to add a checkbox in my report. This checkbox should be checked or unchecked depending on database values.

How do I add a checkbox in Oracle BI Publisher?

Comment: Checkbook? Should this be on the Finance/Money stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here and assuming you mean checkbox instead of checkbook

```
<?if@inlines:YOUR_DATABASE_FIELD = 'Y'?>☑<?end if?>
<?if@inlines:YOUR_DATABASE_FIELD = 'N'?>☐<?end if?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no centrally documented sequence of steps, everyone seems to find different ways to get the checkbox printed. Here is [mine](https://cleartext.blogspot.com/2014/04/check-boxes-not-appearingbi-publisher.html), maybe it helps.